# Azure B2C Session Management

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a React application configured with Azure B2C to support multi-tenant and Microsoft social accounts using a custom policy.

My customer wants to:

- Challenge the user when they access the application if a session has been inactive for 30 minutes.
- Limit the number of sessions a user can open.
- Ensure sessions are aware of password changes and timeouts.

Could someone please provide guidance on how this can be achieved?

I'm thinking of suggesting the below configuration to manage session lifetime.

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
  <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
  <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

OR

```xml
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
  <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
  <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1800</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Can someone validate the above solution and suggest something for

- Limit the number of sessions a user can open.
- Ensure sessions are aware of password changes and timeouts.

Comment: What exactly do they want the behaviour to be when they say "Ensure sessions are aware of password changes and timeouts"?

Comment: Have you tried them and what is the result?